# How to maximize the geometric mean? - SLSQP would be correct?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, logarithms, constraints

I am trying to find a set of weights for each asset in the portfolio, that would give me the highest geometric mean, with only the constraint that all weights must sum up to 1. I'm currently using the SciPy minimize function with a Sequential Least SQuares Programming (SLSQP) method.

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way for achieving the maximum geometric mean, since it's not a quadratic function. What would be the best algorithm for this situation?

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers, $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x_1 \dots x_n}$  with the constraint $g(x) = x_1 + \dots + x_2 - 1 = 0$

Comment: Nice! I will have a look on that. And just for me to understand, what could be the problems of using the SLSQP for that problem, I couldn't find an easy to go explanation on the algorithm. I know that it's used for minimum variance portfolios, but I assume that is because the utility function is quadratic.